# How to completely reset DesktopCouch?

Tags: ubuntu-one, couchdb, desktopcouch

I had been experiencing some Ubuntu One syncing issues that were originating with the local CouchDB. The database has no important information in it, but seems to be persisting across `apt-get purges`. What can I do to reset CouchDB and DesktopCouch to the initial install state?

For whomever is wondering, the current issues I am experiencing is: `Value could not be retrieved. (Unauthorized: ('unauthorized','Authentication required.'))` in the Services tab of the ubuntuone-control-panel. `desktopcouch-service` fails to start because it is receiving a 401 error from couchdb.

Comment: He probably means he also deleted the .ini files in /etc/couchdb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

```
rm -r ~/.config/desktop-couch/
rm -r ~/.local/share/desktop-couch/
rm -r ~/.cache/desktop-couch/
```

and things should start working again.

Comment: This does not fix the issue. The Ubuntu One app is still receiving a 401 error from the CouchDB instance, which suggests that what you gave is not sufficient to reset to a known config. (I also reinstalled all the relevant packages)

Comment: Deleting all of the couchdb config files, as well as the directories you suggested, got it working.

Comment: Which are “all of the couchdb config files” that you deleted in addition to the directories I mentioned? I'll update my answer.

Comment: @chris-whelan Any update on this? I have hit the same issue.  Thanks.